# Authenticating Azure Key Vault using Java

Tags: java, azure, certificate, azure-keyvault

In my previous question i tried to access the Azure Key Vault using clientID and client-secret and get the vault information. Now am trying to access the key vault using clientID and certificate based authentication. I have googled and found [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-java-certificate-authentication). But unable to proceed further, as i could not understand how to proceed further.

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
        client, tenant, pfxCertificatePath, password, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
```

Could someone provide insights what should be the value for tenant and subscriptioID. Also, do i have to provide my certification path in the pfxcertification
Please help me in understanding the above lines of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/AUTH.md) will be helpful.

> Could someone provide insights what should be the value for tenant and
>   subscriptioID.

If my understanding is right, tenant value is your domain name or tenant id. The subscription id is the subscription that you want to manage key vault.

You could create a auth file like below.

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
certificate=<path to certificate file>
certificatePassword=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

Comment: The link is dead, FYI.